# Is there a way to create dummy records without using FOR LOOP?

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot figure out how to put 1000000 dummy data without using FOR LOOP. This is the code I used:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_records (
dummy_id number not null,
dummy_name varchar2(100)
);

BEGIN
    FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO dummy_records (dummy_id, dummy_name) VALUES (loop_counter, dbms_random.value(1,100)); 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

how about simple connect by level?

```
create table mytable as
select level dummy_id,
dbms_random.string('U', 20) dummy_name
from dual connect by level < 1000001
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d677/1

Comment: also here is an article on alot of different ways to generate rows https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

Comment: Tried that, but still showing me an error even if the level < 10.

ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'LIVESQL_USERS'

Comment: ALTER USER <your_user_name> quota unlimited on LIVESQL_USERS;

Answer (score 3):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
insert into dummy_records (dummy_id, dummy_value)
     with cte(n) as (
            select 1 as n
            from dual union all
            select n + 1
             from cte
            where n < 100
           )
     select n, dbms_random.value(1, 100)
     from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=890849782706f173fbcd72687e88ed7a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! But it keeps showing this error when I change it from 100 to 1000000:

ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'LIVESQL_USERS' ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

It does work with 100000.

Comment: @stocke . . . You can run it 10 times.

Comment: @stocke On livesql you have a limited amount of space, it is not meant for heavy loads. That message indicates you have exceeded the allowed space you can use.

Answer (score 0):

All of these solutions are correct but they break because you don't have the temp/rollback space for a million uncommitted rows.   Either do a hundred thousand rows 10 times or use a facility like bulk data load that will allow you to specify a commit interval that is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be

```
create table dummy_records
( dummy_id not null
, dummy_name )
as
select rownum, dbms_random.value(1,100)
from   xmltable('1 to 10');
```

The resulting table will take 21MB. Oracle Live SQL doesn't give you unlimited space, so if you are getting *ORA-01536: space quota exceeded* then you'll need a smaller demo table or a bigger database.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing Gordon Linoff's solution works but I do not know CTEs. An alternative way (which seems to me less elegant, but uses pure SQL so maybe someone will find it useful) would be to use a WITH clause to create a table with 10 VALUES inside, and then cross-join it to itself 6 times to get 1 million rows.